# How to assign a different selector (canceling previous selector method) for a UIButton after execution of some codes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a button name "button1"
i have given a selector for it as below

```
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

now after i have done execution of certain codes. i want this method "buttonPressedMethod:" to be no longer involved in the play.

i want to assign a different selector method. say

```
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(dummymethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

What i am getting now is.

Both the methods are called. i want only one method to be called at a time.
Please give some suggestions to cancel a selector method.

Comment: why don't you make it in two different control events like UIControlEventTouchUpInside and UIControlEventTouchDragOutside

Comment: @VigneshKumar sorry bro.. i dont need it that way.anyways thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 2):

remove your first target before adding the new one:

```
[button1 removeTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try it simple. Create a method and addtarget to the button1 then there do the conditional checkup to call another method like

```
-(void)button1Clicked:(id)sender{

         if(check_your_Condition==true) { [self previousMethod];}

         else { [self laterMethod];}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

have a variable to track current action of the button.

```
SEL currentAction;

// assign action to button using this
currentAction = @selector (newAction:);
[button1 addTarget: self action: currentAction forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// remove previous action action before assigning new one
if (currentAction)
{
    [button1 removeTarget: self action: currentAction forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
// and then reassign action like explained above
```

Answer (score -1):

Maintain one boolean flag . When you want call first selector :

```
if(flag==True)
{
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

After that make flag false where you want.

```
if(flag==false)
{
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(dummymethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Comment: This involves maintaining additional state, and will probably lead to future headaches trying to figure out why. There is no reason to do this when you have `removeTarget:action:forControlerEvents:` instead.

Comment: Yes you r write. In one of my i have did this way.